MUI Variants on Stack and Box
I'm trying to create variants of the  and  components. ie:
export default createTheme({

  components: {
    // Name of the component

    MuiStack: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'sectionHeader' },
          style: {
            padding: 2,
            paddingTop: 1,
            paddingBottom: 0,
            background: "#efefff"
          }
        },
        {
          props: { variant: 'sectionBody' },
          style: {
            padding: 2,
            paddingTop: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
)


Visual Studio Code will highlight the "variant" and say that its not allowed on Stack.  What is the right way the style this.  Do I need to wrap the Stack component with my own to add this styling?  Is there only a subset of components that can have variants?

Have you tried creating custom component ? It seems that Stack component doesn't support the 'variant' prop out of the box. You can create a custom component that wraps the Stack component and adds the variant functionality.
